# How to put different examples for each endpoint in Swagger 2?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a couple of methods in my controller class which are expecting the same Model/Payload class. I have annotated that class properties with `@ApiModelProperty`. I have provided an example value for each of them. Now, when Swagger docs are generated, it uses those values to create a complete example. So far, so good.

The problem starts when I only require some fields in a request. For example, when the request is PATCH on `/endpoint/1`, I only want field X and Z (of possible X, Y, Z). While on another PATCH on `/endpoint/2` requires only Z. PUT and POST requires them all.  However, Swagger shows all the fields for each of the requests. I somehow want to parameterize this based on the endpoint.

Another question would be if there's a way to add JSON as in String format as a response/request example.

Plus, I know a solution can be to create a POJO class for each endpoint. I am looking for a way which doesn't involves creating another class, but doing it using Swagger.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show a value :

```
@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
```

---

**Edit after Comment**

OK, so why don't you dispatch your endpoint, I suppose it looks like

```
@Path("/endpoint1")
...
public void fct1(Optionnal<Object> X, Optionnal<Object> Y, Optionnal<Object> Z){...}
```

couldn't you do

```
@Path("/endpoint1")
...
public void fct1(Optionnal<Object> X, Optionnal<Object> Y, Optionnal<Object> Z){...}

@Path("/endpoint1")
...
public void fct1(Optionnal<Object> X, Optionnal<Object> Y){...}
```

Comment: If I do that then it won't be visible anywhere. I want it to be hidden in some examples, while available in another ones.

Comment: Oh, I think I might have not explained correctly, but hypothetical X, Y and Z are the fields of a Model class which I am accepting. `public Response insert (Payload payload)`, let's say. `Payload` has X, Y, Z fields. And let's say `insert` requires all of them while `changeX` requires only X. Hope, I am clear.